# Converting to a fraction

Tags: java, arrays, methods, int, double

Trying to convert a decimal into a fraction and provide its reciprocal

This is for Java. I tried multiple methods and doing a Math.pow, it is a bit complicated when I already have the answer in decimal form only want to convert it and have the program give the reciprocal

```
public class ParallelSeriesCircuit {
    public static final int SERIES = 1;
    public static final int PARALLEL = 2;

    public int circuitType;
    public double[] resistance;
    public double Rtotal;
    public int Rseries;

    public int getNumberOfResistors() {
        return resistance.length;
    }

    public double getTotalResistance() {
        if (circuitType == SERIES) {

            return getSeriesResistance();
        } else {
            return getParallelResistance();
        }
    }

    public double getParallelResistance() {
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < resistance.length; i++) {
            Rtotal += 1 / resistance[i];


        }

        return Rtotal;
    }

    private double getSeriesResistance() {
        for (int i = 0; i < resistance.length; i++) {
            Rtotal += resistance[i];

        }
        return Rtotal;
    }

}
```

The problem lies in method getParallelResistance as I can't seem to figure out a conversion to a fraction. This is based on user input so that makes it even more complicated

Comment: Remove field `Rtotal` and make it a local variable in the methods that need it. --- Or keep it as a field, but initialize it to 0 at beginning for the two methods, but I wouldn't recommend that.

Answer (score 0):

Formula for Series Resistance is `R = R1 + R2 + R3 + ...` and is correctly calculated by `getSeriesResistance()`.

Formula for Parallel Resistance is `1 / R = 1 / R1 + 1 / R2 + 1 / R3 +...` but that is not what `getParallelResistance()` calculates.

Change to **`return 1 / Rtotal;`**

---

Also, you need to make `Rtotal` a local variable:

```
public double getParallelResistance() {
    double sum = 0;
    for (double r : resistance) {
        sum += 1 / r;
    }
    return 1 / sum;
}

private double getSeriesResistance() {
    double sum = 0;
    for (double r : resistance) {
        sum += r;
    }
    return sum;
}
```